# change a list into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value-store

How do I change a list like this:

```
[[0, 'Ealing Broadway', 103.89],
 [0, 'Notting Hill Gate', 103.89],
 [0, 'Mile End', 103.89],
 [1, 'Ealing Broadway', 59.089999999999996],
 [2, 'Notting Hill Gate', 40.279999999999994],
 [3, 'Mile End', 68.86999999999999]]
```

to a dictionary like

```
{0:{'length':103.89,'interchange':['Ealing Broadway','Notting Hill Gate','Mile End']},
1:{'length':59.089999999999996,'interchange':['Ealing Broadway']},
2:{'length':40.279999999999994,'interchange':['Notting Hill Gate']},
3:{'length':68.86999999999999,'interchange':['Mile End']}}
```

Thanks

```
I am trying to start with:

d2 = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in all_info:
    d2[k].append(v)

with_length=dict((k,list(v)) for k,v in d2.iteritems())
with_length
```

but it does not work, I am struggling where to start.

Comment: Does always same value of first element is sublist indicates same value in last element in sublist?

Comment: I'm intrigued as to what those "lengths" refer to. Platform lengths?

Comment: 0,1,2,3 can be understood as a route. The stations name is the interchange in this route. The final value is the length of the route.

Comment: is it OK for you to use pandas module for the solution?

Comment: I don't think so as I need to deal with a lot of data. Pandas could slow the process.

Comment: @ZXie, ha-ha-ha, read what is pandas designed for ... ;)

Comment: If you have multiple list with same data structure i would suggest using [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)
 so you can access your values with dot notation and it makes code match more readable
    ```from collections import namedtuple
        MyTuple = namedtuple("number", "length", "interchange")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar answer to Majora but using `groupby` first. No false lookups, but could need a sort beforehand.

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [[0, 'Ealing Broadway', 103.89],
    [0, 'Notting Hill Gate', 103.89],
    [0, 'Mile End', 103.89],
    [1, 'Ealing Broadway', 59.089999999999996],
    [2, 'Notting Hill Gate', 40.279999999999994],
    [3, 'Mile End', 68.86999999999999]]

new_list = []
for key, group in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0]):
    new_list.append(list(group))

main_dict = {}
for item in new_list:
    main_dict[item[0][0]] = {'length': item[0][2], 'interchange': [stn[1] for stn in item]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a specific example of how you would do that:

```
l = [[0, 'Ealing Broadway', 103.89],
     [0, 'Notting Hill Gate', 103.89],
     [0, 'Mile End', 103.89],
     [1, 'Ealing Broadway', 59.089999999999996],
     [2, 'Notting Hill Gate', 40.279999999999994],
     [3, 'Mile End', 68.86999999999999]]

d = {}

for pair in l:
    if pair[0] not in d.keys():
        d[pair[0]] = { 'interchange': [] }

    d[pair[0]]['length'] = pair[2]
    d[pair[0]]['interchange'].append(pair[1])
```

This is assuming you want to overwrite `d['length']` when you add an element to `d[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = {}
for i in a:
    if b.has_key(i[0]):
        b[i[0]]['interchange'].append(i[1])
    else:
        b[i[0]] = {'length': i[2], 'interchange': [i[1]]}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as the second edit to my answer.

Comment: @Majora320 It's also not a complete answer to test out. I'm not sure how this has ranked highest. I chose to answer not because I think I have the best, but rather I'd take critique on my own answer if it doesn't suit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which requires two passes. It has the advantage of being easy to understand.

```
import pprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rows = [
        [0, 'Ealing Broadway', 103.89],
        [0, 'Notting Hill Gate', 103.89],
        [0, 'Mile End', 103.89],
        [1, 'Ealing Broadway', 59.089999999999996],
        [2, 'Notting Hill Gate', 40.279999999999994],
        [3, 'Mile End', 68.86999999999999]]

    print('First Pass')
    d = {}
    for key, interchange, length in rows:
        inner_dict = d.setdefault((key, length), {})
        interchanges = inner_dict.setdefault('interchange', [])
        interchanges.append(interchange)

    pprint.pprint(d)

    print('=' * 72)
    print('Second Pass')
    d2 = {}
    for (key, length), v in d.items():
        v['length'] = length
        d2[key] = v

    pprint.pprint(d2)
```

## Output

```
First Pass
{(0, 103.89): {'interchange': ['Ealing Broadway',
                               'Notting Hill Gate',
                               'Mile End']},
 (1, 59.089999999999996): {'interchange': ['Ealing Broadway']},
 (2, 40.279999999999994): {'interchange': ['Notting Hill Gate']},
 (3, 68.86999999999999): {'interchange': ['Mile End']}}
========================================================================
Second Pass
{0: {'interchange': ['Ealing Broadway', 'Notting Hill Gate', 'Mile End'],
     'length': 103.89},
 1: {'interchange': ['Ealing Broadway'], 'length': 59.089999999999996},
 2: {'interchange': ['Notting Hill Gate'], 'length': 40.279999999999994},
 3: {'interchange': ['Mile End'], 'length': 68.86999999999999}}
```

## Discussion

- In the first pass, I use the first and last columns as the key to the dictionary. The value of this dictionary is another dictionary (`inner_dict`)
- In the second pass, I adjust the keys and values to the final form.
- This solution might not be the most efficient or elegant, but I hope that it is easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Please consider my answer as a demonstration of [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) (powerful Python data analysis toolkit) module approach.

I'm pretty sure if you want to process a lot of data **fast** - pandas is your tool...

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[0, 'Ealing Broadway', 103.89],
        [0, 'Notting Hill Gate', 103.89],
        [0, 'Mile End', 103.89],
        [1, 'Ealing Broadway', 59.089999999999996],
        [2, 'Notting Hill Gate', 40.279999999999994],
        [3, 'Mile End', 68.86999999999999]
       ]

# create pandas DF
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['route','interchange','length'])
```

Original DF:

```
In [235]: df
Out[235]:
   route        interchange  length
0      0    Ealing Broadway  103.89
1      0  Notting Hill Gate  103.89
2      0           Mile End  103.89
3      1    Ealing Broadway   59.09
4      2  Notting Hill Gate   40.28
5      3           Mile End   68.87
```

let's group our data:

```
In [239]: df.groupby(['route','length'])['interchange'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()
Out[239]:
   route  length                                     interchange
0      0  103.89  [Ealing Broadway, Notting Hill Gate, Mile End]
1      1   59.09                               [Ealing Broadway]
2      2   40.28                             [Notting Hill Gate]
3      3   68.87                                      [Mile End]
```

we can also convert it to list of dicts:

```
In [240]: df.groupby(['route','length'])['interchange'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index().to_dict('record')
Out[240]:
[{'interchange': ['Ealing Broadway', 'Notting Hill Gate', 'Mile End'],
  'length': 103.89,
  'route': 0},
 {'interchange': ['Ealing Broadway'],
  'length': 59.089999999999996,
  'route': 1},
 {'interchange': ['Notting Hill Gate'],
  'length': 40.279999999999994,
  'route': 2},
 {'interchange': ['Mile End'], 'length': 68.86999999999999, 'route': 3}]
```

Timing for 600.000 rows data frame on my home notebook:

Setup:

```
In [245]: a = pd.concat([df] * 10**5)
```

Shape of merged `a` DF:

```
In [246]: a.shape
Out[246]: (600000, 3)
```

timeit:

```
In [251]: %timeit a.groupby(['route','length'])['interchange'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()
10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop
```

Not-vectorized approach (for loops/list comprehension/etc.):

```
In [262]: %paste
def roganjosh(lst):
    new_list = []
    for key, group in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0]):
        new_list.append(list(group))

    main_dict = {}
    for item in new_list:
        main_dict[item[0][0]] = {'length': item[0][2], 'interchange': [stn[1] for stn in item]}

    return  main_dict
## -- End pasted text --

In [263]: lst = a.values.tolist()

In [264]: len(lst)
Out[264]: 600000

In [265]: %timeit roganjosh(lst)
1 loop, best of 3: 650 ms per loop
```

Comment: You've lost `length`?

Comment: @roganjosh, you are right, thanks! I've corrected my answer

Comment: :) I think it's time for me to hit `timeit` heh

Comment: @roganjosh, yes, please, but do it for 100K - 100M rows please ;)

Comment: @roganjosh, i've added "timeit" results for 600K rows DF, using pandas ;)

Comment: I'm in the process of testing both on 100K loops. Instinct says you're correct but I've found a few operations that were much slower through numpy